# Acer Iconia w510 in recovery, no keyboard

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, system-recovery

My Acer Iconia W510 is stuck in recovery after Windows 8.1 update. I have unfortunately no access to the keyboard docking station. I have found ways to recover the tablet, but all solutions needs the keyboard docking staion.
I have tried to start the tablet with a USB-stick with Windows 8.1 recovery on it, but the computer doesn't recognize the USB-stick when it is inserted through the Micro-USB port (with a Micro-USB to USB wire).

Is there a way to recover the computer without the keyboard docking station?

Comment: Can you not plug a USB keyboard into the micro usb slot? Also you have to alter the security settings in BIOS to enable you to boot from a USB stick. Have you done that?

Comment: I don't have a USB keyboard available. I have changed the BIOS to boot from USB, but it doesn't recognize the USB-stick when it is in the micro-USB port.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the <kbd>volume</kbd> button down and press the <kbd>power</kbd> button at the same time to get into BIOS. Go to the boot menu and selecy `boot from USB HD` above Windows Boot Manager.